# is_post_type_archive is false when I pass GET parameters in the URL

Tags: custom-post-types

So I am modifying the main query and basically asking:

```
if is_post_type_archive('event') {
```

This evaluates to true if the URL is:

http://localhost:8886/jeanmonnetprojects.com.au/event

But is false when I have a get parameter:

http://localhost:8886/jeanmonnetprojects.com.au/event?category=categoryX

I am sure this code was working before and now it's giving me false when I include the GET...any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I had defined the slug as 'events', hence I should have used:

http://localhost:8886/jeanmonnetprojects.com.au/even**t**s?category=categoryX